# Web Service in Java

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, tomcat

When I am creating a Bottom up Java Web Service, it gives an error

> `"IWAB0489E Error when deploying Web service to Axis runtime
>     axis-admin failed with  {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP (400)Bad Request"`

I am using apache-tomcat-7.0.6 server. How can I solve this error?

Comment: check if a similar query at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150698/eclipse-axis-error-when-creating-web-service` answers your problem

Comment: Clickable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150698/eclipse-axis-error-when-creating-web-service

Answer (score 0):

Try using different version of axis. Eg: Axis2 1.4.2.

Make sure Axis2 is loaded correctly in your eclipse
Windows-->Preferences-->webservices-->axis2 preferences check weather axis loaded successfully or not.
Here is the good tutorial for bottom up webservices for beginners.

http://javabottomupwebservices.blogspot.com/